# How to show fallback route using typescript in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code in my `AppRouting` module:

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: 'events',
    data: { preload: true },
    loadChildren: './events/events.module#EventsModule'
  },
  ...
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
...
```

This loads the `Events` module which loads the following `EventsRouting` module:

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: EventsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: EventsListComponent
  }
  ...
];
...
```

In the `EventsComponent` constructor I make an `http.get` call to the website's backend:

```
constructor(...) {

  route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  let eventId = params.get("id");
  http.get<EventDTObject>(baseUrl + "api/v1/Events/Get/" + eventId).subscribe(result => {

      if (result==null) router.navigate(['/404']);
      this.eventDTObject = result;

    }, error => console.error(error));
  });
}
```

All of this works the way I would like, except for the line

```
if (result==null) router.navigate(['/404']);
```

While it does redirect the user to the correct PageNotFoundComponent, the user can no longer press the back button on the browser to go back. This is because every time the previous page is loaded, it results in the 404 error again through the `http.get` request.

I imagine some sort of solution where instead of changing (hence redirecting) the current route to `"/404"`, it would be possible to show the fallback route `"**"` in the root routing module using typescript. The same way you are not redirected to, but shown the component of the fallback route `"**"` if you try to access a route that is not specified in the `AppRouting` module.

Something like:

```
http.get<...>(...).subscribe(result => {
  if (result==null) router.showDefaultRoute();
  ...
}
```

Is this possible?

(note the nested routing)

Comment: You should look into route resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

Location Service and "Back" function should do the work. Location Service should be imported from "angular2/router" in older versions of Angular 2. For newer "@angular/common". Below is case when you have back button in your form.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';


@Component({ directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] })
@RouteConfig([
    {...},
])
class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _location: Location) {
    }
    backClicked() {
        this._location.back();
    }
}
```

In case for back button clicked on webbrowser use [PlatformLocation](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation) and then you can define **onPopState**.

```
this.location.onPopState(()=>{
  this.location.back();
});
```

Comment: Even if the browser goes back to the page. It will throw the 404 error again because the `http.get` request is made by that page.